# Function of shared library is loaded at different physical addresses for different processes

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, elf

I get physical addresses of function "printf" in libc.so in two programs, and two physical addresses are different. And I read two different physical address, the content are almost the same. This means function "printf" has two copies in memory?

Details:

1. My os is 32-bit linux.
2. Physical address is calculated by read "/proc/self/pagemap".
3. Physical address reading is implemented with fmem module, whose source code is at git@github.com:NateBrune/fmem.git

Comment: What do you mean by "the content are almost the same"? If the two `printf()` implementations differ, then of course they have to be in different places, perhaps the two programs use different versions of libc?

Comment: "*physical addresses*" are you sure? Each process uses its own *virtual*  address space.

Comment: It could be [address space layout randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

Comment: This is how most dynamic linker works now: it loads the shared library again and again for each process that uses the library. Ideally each process's memory access is isolated from any other's so that they are protected from each other. This applies to both code and data, e.g. you don't want one buggy process to corrupt or compromise another process's code. So it's easier and safer to load the library multiple times for each process than loading the dynamic library once and map the memory location multiple times for multiple processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get physical addresses of function "printf" in libc.so in two programs, and two physical addresses are different.

You are probably doing it wrong (but it's hard to guess: you didn't provide any details).

In particular, note that the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("&printf: %p\n", &printf);
  return 0;
}
```

does *not* print the actual address of `printf` in `libc.so.6`, as can be observed with GDB:

```
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x8048426: file pagemap.c, line 5.
Starting program: /tmp/pagemap

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at pagemap.c:5
5     printf("&printf: %p\n", &printf);
(gdb) n
&printf: 0x80482f0
6     return 0;

(gdb) info symbol 0x80482f0
printf@plt in section .plt of /tmp/pagemap

(gdb) p &printf
$1 = (<text variable, no debug info> *) 0xf7e5add0 <printf>

(gdb) info sym 0xf7e5add0
printf in section .text of /lib32/libc.so.6
```

Note that `printf @0x80482f0` is in the main executable, and is *not* supposed to be shared (except between multiple instances of the same executable running at the same time), and is *not* where code for `printf` actually resides.

The `printf @0xf7e5add0` is in `libc.so.6`, and *that* is where code for `printf` actually is. *That* page is supposed to be shared by all processes using `libc.so.6`.

P.S. To get the *actual* address of `printf` in `libc.so.6`, one may use this program instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main()
{
  printf("&printf: %p\n", &printf);
  printf("&printf: %p\n", dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "printf"));
  return 0;
}

gcc -g pagemap.c -o pagemap -m32 -ldl -D_GNU_SOURCE

(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/pagemap
&printf: 0x80483c0
&printf: 0xf7e55dd0

(gdb) info sym 0xf7e55dd0
printf in section .text of /lib32/libc.so.6
```

Comment: I got a question.. I thought that the symbol name in the plt is `printf@plt`. But why does `dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "printf")` find the plt entry? Why does the plain non-plt'ed symbol-string not find the real thing like it apparently did with `gdb`?

Comment: @litb "I thought that the symbol name in the plt is printf@plt" -- it's not. It's `printf` as you can see in `readelf -Ws` output. The `@plt` is a name that GDB manufactures to make it clearer what that symbol is.

Comment: @EmployedRussian, you are right, the virtual address of 'printf' I got is actually that of 'printf@plt', the real virtual address of ‘printf’ is stored in GOT after 'printf' is bound. Finally in my experiment，I got virtual addresses 0xb7581590 and 0xb7635590 of 'printf' in two programs, and their physical addresses are both 0x7bc6b590.

Comment: @EmployedRussian my test output doesn't contain `printf`, but `printf@GLIBC_2.2.5`. But still searching for `printf` with `RTLD_DEFAULT` gave a different result than with `RTLD_NEXT`. Does this mean that the dynamic linker will match `printf` against the symbol `printf@GLIBC_2.2.5` at runtime? Those are version-suffixes, and I'm not sure how they match a non-suffixed symbol at runtime. Any idea where to look this up?

Comment: Ah, we have `dlvsym` which requires version match and `dlsym` which can find the symbol even of different versions.